# How to use `svelte-spa-router` when `customElement: true`?

Tags: components, svelte, custom-element

I use it like this:

```
<script>
import Router from "svelte-spa-router";
</script>
<Router routes={{}} />
```

and I got some compile-time warn and runtime error:

[compile-time warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrQ1z.png)

[runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrCHl.png)

ah, and, when I trying to use other components that haven't `<svelte:options tag="xxx" />` tag, I got those warn/error too.

so...how?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should set tag as "xxx-yyy";
2. Set svelte({
   compilerOptions: {
   customElement: true
   }})
   in vite or rollup config